# how to create a dictionary in Python by User input

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.7

I have a specific format of dictionary with network vertices and edge cost and i want to create it by user input

The format in python i want is a nested dict to dict:

```
   graph = {'a':{'b':10,'c':3},'b':{'c':1,'d':2},'c'{'b':4,'d':8,'e':2},'d':{'e':7},'e':{'d':9}}
```

Code so far:

```
while True:        
graph = dict()

user_input = input("Enter key and value separated by commas (,): ")

key, value = user_input.split(",")
if user_input == "":
  break

my_dict[key] = value
```

The result is not what  i want because i want for every vertices multible edges with costs

Comment: Have you considered using a for loop?

Comment: I was thinking like creating 2 dictionary and then mix it into one.The first will have the vertices and the second the edges with cost

Comment: Don't you need 3 inputs from user instead of 2? `source_node`, `destination_node` and `edge_cost` ? Like if `a, b, 10` is the input, i think graph should be `{'a' : {'b': 10}}` ?

Comment: Yes like the example of graph written in python above, but for 'a' in this case i want {'b':10,'c':15,'d':20}} and so on...